# Android resource linking fail in Android -3.1.24?

Tags: android, android-mvvm, android-studio-3.1

I am Work on MVVM module app and Getting error : -  C:\Users\123.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\67afe2b5b1b4fe8a866b1004d9b96c04\core-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

I have use this dependencies : -

```
dependencies {
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"

// Dependencies for working with Architecture components
// You'll probably have to update the version numbers in build.gradle (Project)

// Room components
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

// Lifecycle components
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"

// UI
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.materialVersion"

// Testing
testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.coreTestingVersion"
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion", {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$rootProject.androidxJunitVersion"
```

}

**Virsion is**

```
ext {
appCompatVersion = '1.3.0'
constraintLayoutVersion = '2.0.4'
coreTestingVersion = '2.1.0'
lifecycleVersion = '2.3.1'
materialVersion = '1.3.0'
roomVersion = '2.3.0'
// testing
junitVersion = '4.13.2'
espressoVersion = '3.1.0'
androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.2'
```

}